# TextStyle lineHeight does not work for single line text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, line-height

I am setting TextStyle to my Text composable, but when the text is multi-line, only then the line height works as expected.

But, in case the text is single line, line height is not applied to it.

When I checked the documentation of TextStyle, I got to know that the lineHeight is applied on the *Paragraph*.

[image]

Is there a way lineHeight can be applied to single line text as well? Or is there some other attribute which I am unaware of?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

lineHeight never works on single line on both xml and compose, as a workaround for both you can set minHeight as the desired lineHeight, also set text to be centered vertically.

```
@Composable
fun SingleLineText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    style: TextStyle = Text1Regular.copy(color = AppTheme.colors.textPrimary),
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null
) {
    Text(
        modifier = modifier
            .defaultMinSize(minHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { style.lineHeight.toDp() })
            .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically),
        text = text,
        style = style,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = overflow,
        textAlign = textAlign
    )
}
```

the key point here is these two lines

```
.defaultMinSize(minHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { style.lineHeight.toDp() })
.wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically),
```

first line to set lineHeight from your style as minHeight. 
second line to center the text vertically.

BONUS for xml ->

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_textview"
    style="@style/your_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" // <-------
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minHeight="28sp"  // <-------
    tools:text="Name Surname" />
```